# PreviewlostkeyboardFocus event fires twice when I click on combobox WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have wired `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event to `TextBox`. I handled the event. When I click on the `ComboBox` control, it fires twice.

If I not handled it fires only one time.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Can someone please help resolve this issue ?

Comment: Why is this an issue? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It should fire once. If it does twice, you should check your code if there is anything that put focus back to TextBox. Check code that is related to that ComboBox if anything gives focus automatically back to the Textbox. E.G Your code could give focus back to textbox after you have chosen an item in combobox.

Comment: @almulo  When textbox having invalid data i want to keep focus back to text box.

Comment: @JonKoivula , we didn't write any code related to combobox.

Answer (score 0):

When you set:

```
e.Handled = True;
```

You are effectively preventing the focus leaving the TextBox.

So if focus is in this TextBox and you click on another field (e.g. ComboBox) it will cause the event to fire, but the cursor will remain forever in the TextBox.

Remove this or make it conditional.

Comment: Yes, i don't want focus leave from text box when it has invalid data. if i make conditional also, PreviewLostKeyboardFocus gets fired twice.

once the new focus is ComboBoxControl

Second time from ComboBoxItem

when i click on button it gets fired only once.

if its the default behavior.

can we have any work around for this?

Comment: You don't need a workaround.  Just don't set e.Handled to True unless the validation fails.